# Eclipse SourceVIew doesn't hightlight comments with JavaSourceViewerConfiguration

Tags: eclipse

I develop Eclipse plugin.
I want to show highlighted java code in my ViewPart.

I try to use integrated Eclipse classes (`SourceViewer` with `JavaSourceViewerConfiguration`). Here is my code:

```java
@Override
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    String code = "int a = 5;\n" + 
            "//not-working comment\n" +
            "/* not working single line comment */ \n" +
            "not-working multi-line comment\n";

    JavaTextTools tools= JavaPlugin.getDefault().getJavaTextTools();
    SourceViewer sv = new SourceViewer(parent, null, SWT.NONE);

    JavaSourceViewerConfiguration config = 
            new JavaSourceViewerConfiguration(
            tools.getColorManager(),
            JavaPlugin.getDefault().getCombinedPreferenceStore(),
            null,
            null
            ); 
    sv.configure(config);
    Document d = new Document();
    d.set(code);
    sv.setDocument(d);
}
```

It successfully highlights all code, but doesn't highlight any comments.  What I do wrong?

UPD:
I'm not sure if it is important, but there is list of plugins/packages marked in manifest file as required:

```
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 org.eclipse.jdt.ui,
 org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor,
 org.eclipse.jface.text
Import-Package: org.eclipse.jface.text.source
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to specify the partitioning parameter (last argument of the `JavaSourceViewerConfiguration` constructor) as `IJavaPartitions.JAVA_PARTITIONING`.

Comment: If I add any argument from `IJavaPartitions` constants, highlighting totally disappears. And I hasn't any exceptions/errors.
This is very strange.

Comment: The main `JavaEditor` also uses `JavaSourceViewer` as the source viewer which does all sorts of things. `JavaSourceViewer` is an internal class so should not be used.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a partitioner for the document:

```
IDocumentPartitioner partitioner = new FastPartitioner(new FastJavaPartitionScanner(), new String[] { 
        IJavaPartitions.JAVA_DOC,
        IJavaPartitions.JAVA_MULTI_LINE_COMMENT, 
        IJavaPartitions.JAVA_SINGLE_LINE_COMMENT,
        IJavaPartitions.JAVA_STRING, IJavaPartitions.JAVA_CHARACTER });
```

and then connect both of them:

```
d.setDocumentPartitioner(partitioner);
partitioner.connect(d);
```